# C with a module system

Tags: c++, c, module

In the history of the C language, have any experiments been done towards adding a module system?

I know about the C++ proposal which didn't make the latest standard. I'm thinking of something more along the lines of particular implementations which added a module system as a non-standard feature.

By "module system" I mean something which at the very least allowed the user to write one file instead of a .h/.c pair.

Comment: One writes a pair of files in order to separate interface from implementation. There is no need for a pair, but then it gets harder to separate the two. Perhaps you would be interested in looking at Pascal or Delphi, with their concept of "units", instead.

Comment: FWIW, Delphi does _not_ separate interface and implementation into two files. A unit has an interface section, which is publicly accessible and only contains declarations and an implementation section which is private to the unit, and which contains, well, implementation.

Comment: @Ignacio There are other ways of realising this. For instance, the interface can be auto-generated by the compiler. Virtually every modern programming language includes some version of this, where the compiler is perfectly happy to do the separation for the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

[D programming language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/module.html) is a C++-like language with a module system. I'm not aware of any module system designed for plain C.

Comment: Vala is another language with modules. It's interesting in that the current implementation translates Vala code to C. Every Vala library is a valid C library.

Answer (score 3):

[Makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr) is a related utility.

Answer (score 2):

The creators of C did indeed explore these things in the languages (including extensions to C) developed for [Plan 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs). Check out [Limbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo_%28programming_language%29).

Answer (score 1):

Apple is [working on adding a module system](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/modules-update-video-available-doug-gregor) to the LLVM C++ implementation.